# How to auto replace into lambda expressions in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, lambda

I enabled lambda expressions in Android Studio and it works fine, but each time I use shortcuts to write down a new interface it shows in the pre-Java-8 form and not in a lambda expression and I have to manually replace it each time.!

Is there a way to let Android Studio to auto replce ot lambda expression?

see here what I mean =>

[image]

Comment: have set your source and target compatibility to 1.8?

Comment: [java-8-for-android-cleaner-code-with-lambda-expressions](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/java-8-for-android-cleaner-code-with-lambda-expressions--cms-29661)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set compile options and set source and target compatibility to `1.8` in your `build.gradle`. Now whenever you type the listener simply using `ctrl+space` will show lambda as option for auto-fill.

[image]

Comment: oh, I get it now, I was typing `new` then I click `ctrl+space` that's why! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to replace all the lambda expression from the project 
you can try 
***Ctrl + Shift+ Alt  + I***
on inspection search tab, search **anonymous type can be replaced with lambda**.
It will replace all the anonymous type to lambda.

Comment: With Studio 3.5.3 on "Ctrl + Shift+ Alt + I" a popup titled "Enter inspection name:" will appear and you should insert there literally a text "anonymous type can be replaced with lambda". When find results will be displayed you should select there all the classes (Ctrl-A) and then click Replace button to do replace in a one operation.

Comment: With Studio 2020.3.1 arctic fox the option to replace can only be selected on a single line (after expanding the class). When selecting the whole class or select all there is only the option to ignore this in the (next) inspection. BAD.